# What's the relation of FDR and Wilson to War on Terror/terrorism?

Tags: historical-accuracy, house-of-cards, politics

In House of Cards, Frank Underwood brings up FDR and Wilson when saying that he wants to declare war on ICO (fictional terrorist group possibly related to ISIS). What's the relation please? I mean, every president presumably has to deal with terrorism in some way so why those presidents specifically?

Comment: Don't crosspost.

Comment: @JamesK You can cross post if you don't get good enough answers in other subs. Math overflow and stats se do this too re maths se. Same with anime se and jap se.

Comment: @BCLC I think it would make sense to have asked this on **either** Politics or Movies & TV after it was closed on History, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Also, as requested on History, we’ll really need a more precise quote to even begin to speculate. Also those presidents didn’t have to deal with terrorism as much as they had to deal with war. That’s much more likely to be the link.

Comment: @ToddWilcox [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) ?

Comment: This seems to be the most appropriate SE for this question.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know what "brings up" actually means.  Do you have the lines anywhere?  You can often get them by turning on closed-captioning.

Comment: Crossposting questions to multiple SE sites shouldn't be done as per SE policy. See the Meta SE FAQ post: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/162827)

Comment: @galacticninja I've been getting around that for 8 years now.

Comment: @BCLC And you happened to be "lucky" this time, too, as both coss-posts turned out to be inappropriate for the sites they were asked on anyway. Hadn't they been closed, this question would have gone the way of all mortal things, too. Rather than that, we'll just try to forget you ever posted this on any other sites to begin with (together with this question). ;-)

Comment: “I’ve been cross posting for years despite knowing I’m not supposed to do it so now that you’re telling me I’m not supposed to do I’m going to act like it’s ok because I want it to be ok even though I know it’s not ok.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the transcript, [House of Cards, Season 5, Episode 1](https://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/house-of-cards-2013-7mpe/s5/e1), Frank Underwood, addressing the House of Representatives.

> One of the murderers who killed Mr. Jim Miller is still out there.
>
> At large.
>
> How much proof do you need?
>
> I demand that every member of this House take a stand.
>
> Like FDR before, and Wilson before him.
>
> I demand that this Congress declare a formal declaration of war against ICO, both here and abroad.

Congress, for Wilson (WWI) and FDR (WWII), passed formal declarations of war under the US Constitution, [Article 1, Section 8, Clause 11](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S8-C11-1/ALDE_00001072/):

> To declare War, grant Letters of Marque and Reprisal, and make Rules concerning Captures on Land and Water;

Frank Underwood is demanding the same — a formal declaration of war — as was provided Wilson and FDR.

In a case of art imitating life, a Joint Resolution was introduced in the US Senate, [S.J.Res.46 - Declaration of War against the Organization known as the Islamic State](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/46), more that two years before the referenced *House of Cards* episode aired.

Comment: This answer is identical to my answer on Politics SE https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/75146/26455.